# Having difficulty making a self-calculating handson table in R

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I am making an applet that should already have a handson table generated upon opening. 
When the user finishes inputting data into the one column of the handson table, he presses the submit button, and then I want R shiny to automatically begin doing certain calculations that fills out the values in all other columns in the table. This is why I call it self-calculating. Here is the pertinent code:

```
server <- function(input,output){
   df_old <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow= dim(as.matrix(category))[1], ncol = 3))
   df_new <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow= dim(as.matrix(category))[1], ncol = 3))

   output$tbl <- renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable(df_old) 
      })

    df_new<<- eventReactive(input$submit,{
      df_old<<- as.data.frame(df_new)
      table<-as.data.frame(hot_to_r(input$tbl))
      df_new<- comparison(DF_old,table,CDF)
      })
    output$tbl <- renderRHandsontable({
      rhandsontable(df_new()) 
    })
    }
```

`output$tbl` refers to the `rhandson` table I initialized in the `ui`. First I initialize 2 `df` values. I need an old `df` value with old values and a new `df` variable that stores new values so I can compare them before doing calculations in a separate `comparison function`. Then the original blank `tbl` is initialized. I then tell R to assign new values to `df_new` when the `submit button` is pressed. `comparison` returns a new `dataframe` that would then be returned to `df_new`. I THEN made a second `renderRHandsontable`, hoping that because `df_new` is now **reactive**, **it would always re-render the table** whenever `df_new` changes. But all i currently get is this:

```
Warning: Error in do.call: second argument must be a list
  131: stop
  130: do.call
  129: hot_to_r
  127: eventReactiveHandler [C:/Users/Mykhalo Petrovskyy/Desktop/Accessible Project/R_Econ_App/new.R#59]
   83: df_new
   79: func [C:/Users/Mykhalo Petrovskyy/Desktop/Accessible Project/R_Econ_App/new.R#63]
   78: origRenderFunc
   77: output$tbl
    1: runApp
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What is `input$tbl`?

Comment: @VisheshShrivastav the input$tbl is referring to this ui code:
  mainPanel(rHandsontableOutput("tbl") )

Comment: Can you share your ui code as well?